# underscore js findWhere find object with just key value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that lists all users, and each new connection gets added to this array along with the file name they uploaded. An example after two people have uploaded a file each is:

```
[ '{ 127.0.2.2: test.pdf}', '{ 127.0.0.1: asf.pdf}' ]
```

How would I return the file name with just the IP? If needed, I can split the file name later if returning the IP + file name works.

I've tried:

```
console.log(_.findWhere(userlist, function(){ var tempObj = {}; return tempObj[user] = fileName;}));
```

But this just returns the first value, every time. Using the example, it would return {127.0.2.2: test.pdf} every time. user and fileName are defined after someone uploads, so they should overwrite with the current information (which is proven right, as it adds it correctly), but it still just returns the first key/value pair every time.

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: underscore's findWhere does not take a function as its second argument

Comment: It takes a literal string, which won't work for searching for user as a variable. Putting what I'm searching for in a function seems to be significantly close than just {user: fileName}, as none of them contain {user: fileName}.

Comment: Indeed. So use the correct function, `_.find`

Comment: ._find still gives the first result. Unless this is an issue with testing to my VM from outside through port forwarding... [ '{ 10.0.0.2: test.pdf }', '{ 127.0.0.1: asf.pdf }' ] --> { 10.0.0.2: test.pdf } even using 127.0.0.1...

Comment: It would look something like: `_.find(userList, function(user){ return user.indexOf(fileName)>-1});`. Note that your data is kind of weird, since it is just a string and not JSON or something, hence the indexOf search

Comment: Hmm... Yours worked but The ZenCoder's didn't. Thanks Brennan.

Comment: It's because the data you have is different than how he interpreted. You'r data is a string that contains an IP and image name. My solution will work, but it is brittle, so be careful with that.

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be used rarely, and by few people. Maybe once a month. Should work fine enough for now.

Answer (score 2):

As Brennan stated in the comments you should use _.find instead of your current code.

```
var userlist = [ { '127.0.2.2': 'test.pdf'}, { '127.0.0.1': 'asf.pdf'} ];

var ip = '127.0.0.1';

var userWithIp = _.find(userlist, function(f){ return Object.keys(f)[0] === ip;})
```

Here is working code using the _.find method:

http://jsfiddle.net/g49urmef/1/